# How to convert a number to a three-character string using an Oracle sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ddl

I need to create an Oracle 12c sequence and convert it from a number to a three-character string that has the format of `001`, `002`, `003` etc.

Here is an example of a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE supplier_seq
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 1;
```

Taking the above sequence, I now need to convert it to a three character string as shown above.

Comment: A number doesn't have leading zeros. You *could* store it as a zero-padded string, but generally you would keep it as a number. How will you use this, to supply a primary key value? What data type is the table column you will populate with the sequence?

Comment: Yes, of course - the sequence is numeric. Assuming I leave the sequence as is and from the looks of it, the data type of the column is VARCHAR2 - would I just use LPAD?

Comment: i would say, that you cant increment varchar2. you can handle it in before insert trigger

Comment: @hotfix - sounds good.

Comment: If your question is how to convert a number to a three-character string then I'd use `to_char(supplier_seq.nextval, 'FM000')`. But it depends what you're doing with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help all - updated original question. @AlexPoole if you could pls add you comment as a solution, that would be great.

Comment: You use the generated sequence to produce **numeric** values for a primary key column (presumably). The `003` format is **only** related to presentation (reports and such). The best option is to keep the values in numeric format. Whenever you need to *present* them as strings, use `to_char(supplier_seq, 'fm009')`. Notice the fm, in particular; without it the numbers will have a leading space (placeholder for sign, plus or minus).

Comment: @Radagast81 - that is not how sequences work in Oracle.

Comment: What is the benefit storing a numeric value as a character string padded with leading zeroes? Enquiring minds want to know.

Comment: @APC thanks for clarification, but i think you can still get gaps of 20 with cache set to 20 which you want to avoid if you only have 1k values in the sequence. I know that gaps in sequences are ok, but with this low number of possible values you want to avoid them as best as you can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using the only sequence.

But yes you can use the following function, wherever sequence is used, to convert the values of sequence to the required format.

```
SELECT LPAD(supplier_seq.nextval,3,0) FROM DUAL; -- 001, 002, 003
```

Hope, This is what you are looking for.